# How do I delete a network connection in Windows 8.1?

Tags: windows, networking, virtualbox

I can't delete a network connection. I have dozens of these connections cluttering up my network panel. How do I remove them?

[image]

Comment: https://www.howtogeek.com/176148/how-to-%E2%80%9Cforget%E2%80%9D-a-wired-or-wireless-network-in-windows-8.1/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can first try to go to your Device Manager, expand the network adapters, right click virtualbox related network adapters and uninstall them.

If it cannot solve the problem, you have to delete the VIRTUALBOX DRIVERS in C:\Windows\System32\drivers\ and Registry Editor. For more details, please refer to:
https://dottech.org/101997/how-to-uninstall-virtualbox-drivers-on-windows/

Comment: Please quote and cite the relevant information from your external resource.